# How to make this J Query/Ajax script work with more than one row record?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a table with records from a database which is dynamically filled.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>name
   </td>
   <td>surname
   </td>
   ...
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Name'];?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Surname'];?>
    </td>
...
<td align="center">
    <form name="form" action="novi.php">
    <input name="check" type="radio" value="da">Да
    <input name="check" type="radio" value="ne">Не
    <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>">
    <input class="button1"type="button" id="klik" value="Испрати"/>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
```

And than I'm using J Query to create an AJAX call to another page which will run the query.

```
<script>
$('#klik').click(function() {
var check = $("input[name='check']:checked").val();
var id = $('#id').val();
if (check == "da")
{
    $.post('sluzbaIncludes/n.php', {check:check, id:id}, function(data) {

        $('#klik').prop('value', (data));
        document.location.reload();

    });
}
else if (check == "ne")
{
    $.post('sluzbaIncludes/n.php', {check:check, id:id}, function(data) {

    $('#klik').prop('value', (data));
    document.location.reload();

});
}
else
{
    $('#klik').prop('value', 'Грешка');
    setTimeout("$('#klik').prop('value', '.')",500);
    setTimeout("$('#klik').prop('value', '..')",1000);
    setTimeout("$('#klik').prop('value', '...')",1500);
    setTimeout("$('#klik').prop('value', 'Испрати')",2000);

}
```

});

This is working OK if there is only one row in the table.
What I don't know how to do is, to make the script store all the generated CHECKED radio buttons in an array or something, plus all the ID's of the records from the database and send them to another page where according to their ID's a query will update the database..

```
<?php
if ($_POST['id'] != NULL) {
if ($_POST['check'] == "da") {
       $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
   $update = mysql_query("update korisnici set validacija = 1 where id_korisnici= '$id'");
        if ($update === true) {
        echo 'OK';

    }else if ($update === false){
        echo 'Error!!!';
    }
}
elseif ($_POST['check'] == "ne")
{
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $update = mysql_query("update korisnici set validacija = 2 where id_korisnici= '$id'"); 
    if ($update === true) {
            echo 'OK';

        }
    else if ($update === false){
            echo 'Error!!!';
        }
}
} else {
echo 'Error!!!';
}
?>
```

Thanks!
P.S. I'm a noob in JQuery and a beginner in PHP...

**UPDATE:**

I did change some things. And now the values are shown as I want, when I click the button without a selection I'm getting the error message in the ELSE part of the JQuery code in the proper button. But no matter which button I click (if the table is populated with 3 records from the database, there are 3 buttons) **only the first row from the table** is updated in the database.

```
<form name="form" action="novi.php">
           <input name="check<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>" type="radio" value="da">Да
           <input name="check<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>" type="radio" value="ne">Не
           <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>">
           <input class="button1"type="button" id="klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>" value="Испрати"/>
            </form>
```

The JQuery:

```
$('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').click(function() {
var check = $("input[name='check<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>']:checked").val();
var id = $('#id').val();


if (check == "da")
{
    $.post('sluzbaIncludes/n.php', {check:check, id:id}, function(data) {

        $('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', (data));
        document.location.reload();

    });
}
else if (check == "ne")
{
    $.post('sluzbaIncludes/n.php', {check:check, id:id}, function(data) {

    $('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', (data));
    document.location.reload();

});
}
else
{
    $('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', 'Error');
    setTimeout("$('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', '.')",500);
    setTimeout("$('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', '..')",1000);
    setTimeout("$('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', '...')",1500);
    setTimeout("$('#klik<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>').prop('value', 'Send')",2000);

}
```

});

Comment: Looks like all of your radio buttons share the same name, meaning you'll only ever be able to select one radio button on that page. Is this what you're experiencing?

Comment: I realized that now.. That shouldn't be happening. I'd like every record from the database to have a group of two radio buttons.
<pre><input name="check<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>" type="radio" value="da">Да
<input name="check<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_korisnici'];?>" type="radio" value="ne">Не
<post>
This would solve that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make each group of radio buttons have a unique name but the same class. Then you can iterate through them using jQuery:

```
var radioVals = new Array();
var i = 0;
$(".radioButtonClass:checked").each(function() { 
    radioVals[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

Then just pass the array in your ajax call.

Comment: @MiteStojanov Edited for completeness.